# Full Referrer not showing full URL

Tags: google-analytics, referrer

I am trying to exclude "Affirm.com" from my analytics property. I have already added "affirm.com" to my referral exclusion list, but I am still getting results for "affirm" in my channel report.

Is there any reason that it is showing just "affirm" under the Full Referrer and not "affirm.com"? It is also showing just affirm for the source, medium, and campaign.

[screenshot of the GA results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZQqP.png)

Thanks - let me know if you need more details. (Affirm is a payment system similar to Paypal)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you pass it to Analytics with **UTM** parameters.